# When does a process acquire a file to read

Tags: linux, process

I have a script that takes a list of servers from an input file one by one and executes some commands on each server. I want to be able to update the input file while this script is running, without affecting the input of the first process, and re-run the script with the second list of servers. Can this be done safely?

Comment: I believe you're asking "*If I write to a file while a program is reading it, what will happen?*" - is that correct?

Comment: yes, and i am interested to know , when a process acquire all the resources, like the inputs from the file here..

Comment: Also now writing to input file , replacing entire contents of input file

Comment: What do you mean "*acquire all the resources*"? What "resources" are you referring to? The file being read?

Comment: Yes I mean the input file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run a command like `file > my_script` the contents located at `file` are piped into `my_script` (as a [file descriptor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor)). This decouples the contents from the name, meaning you can immediately modify/replace `file` in another process.

If you instead run a command like `my_script file` you're passing the *name* "file" to `my_script`, which may read from that file at any point (or write to it, delete it, etc.), thus you can't safely change `file` while the script is running. Notably this doesn't happen immediately; a long running process might not read from `file` until much later, after you've already edited the file.

Therefore if you design your program to read from stdin you can safely modify the input file and re-run the command while the first process is still running.

Comment: @AravindVijayan glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

Let say that your process is running and if you want to change the file, just mv the file aside and copy your new input file. That way if the process hasn't completely read the input file into memory, it will still have a file-descriptor open to the previous file and will run unaffected. Ofcourse this all depends on how the process is implemented, if it tries to re-open the file during the course of execution, it will see new files contents.

```
process inputfile
mv inputfile inputfile.running
mv newinput inputfile
```

Comment: Thank you, consider there is a for loop in bash script to read server names one by one, I was thinking when we can remove entities from input file supply new server names and run another instance of same script